# Unsuported OpenGL functions and constants

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

My program works fine in windows environment, but when trying to compile it on android, I get errors about not declared functions and constants. These include:

```
GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8,
GL_DEPTH_STENCIL,
GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8,
GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,
glPointSize()
```

Other methods seem to work fine.
I include these headers for graphics:

```
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
```

Am I missing something, or I really can't use these constants and function?

Comment: if they are not supported, then no - you can not use them

Comment: But how do I know if they're unsupported or not? Compiler only says they were not declared in this scope. So maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: see for example this : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150/what-is-the-difference-between-opengl-es-and-opengl

Comment: You can set point size within vertex shader, see vertex shader built-in variable ``gl_PointSize``.

Comment: As I can remember these features are not available in embeded environment. Try checking OpenGL ES 2.0 reference.

Comment: How else would I implement render to texture? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that you are using immediate or Opengl desktop functions on your desktop machine which is compatible with any version of OpenGL while they do not work on the ES version of OpenGL. For instance many people implement their first engines in immediate mode and then they try to port on OpenGL ES 2.0 devices.

OpenGL ES 2.0 has its own functions set that you can find in the official documentation. http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/

To take one of the reported functions, the glpointsize is not supported in OpenGL ES 2.0 since you control the size of the point in your shaders and not in the main code as you do in immediate mode.
In this very particular size, the point sprite (very roughly) is controlled in your vertex shader with a function like:

gl_PointSize = 10.0;

This is a typical case where you realize that the porting to OpenGL ES 2.0 sometimes requires a complete rewriting of your engine.

Comment: Well, I can always pass point size as uniform, so it is not a problem. The problem is with rendering into depth texture. Is it even possible?